# How to use Multiple token source words in wordforms with (maybe) "masks"?

Tags: sphinx

I'm finding issues with creating multi-word wordforms

```
Word1 Word2 > Word3 Word4
```

when any of those words are part of prior or subsequent wordforms (doesn't matter in fact the order)

```
Word5 > Word1
Word6 > Word2
```

Any combination of the above words will work e.g.

```
"Word5 Word6"="Word1 Word2"="Word1 Word6"="Word5 Word2"
```

And naturally

```
"Word1 Word2" = "Word3 Word4"
```

However if I do any substitutions in the mutlitoken wordform e.g

```
"Word5 Word2" != "Word3 Word4"
```

and

```
"Word1 Word6" != "Word4 Word4"
```

So far the only (clumsy) solution I found is to make a version of all the possible mutltoken versions in the left side:

```
Word1 Word2 > Word3 Word4
Word5 Word2 > Word3 Word4
Word1 Word6 > Word3 Word4
Word5 Word6 > Word3 Word4
```

I've found I am not forced to do the same on the right/destination wordforms.

Is there a better solution?  In the documentation I read:

> ..you can specify several files and not only just one. Masks can be
>   used as a pattern, and all matching files will be processed in simple
>   ascending order.

Would this indicate a possible solution, i.e. a first wordform with single token wordforms and then a second wordform to process mutlitokens?

Comment: That comment, is just mentioning you can specify multiple distnct wordform files in the config file. Rather than having to physically combine sperate files, can just specify multiple directly

Comment: @Barryhunter Yes thanks I checked whether the stacked worforms solved and it did not. So far my only solution is the brute force one (when doing mutli token wordforms I need to manually store each version of replaced internal token (Large Car, Big Auto,etc).  For some reason however this does not happen when I do a multi token term. For instance assuming stemming is off, if I do IPO>Initial Public Offering and Offer > Offering then IPO will map to both 'Initial Public Offering' and 'Initial Public Offer' so the two-step mapping works, it is only when the multiple word tokens are on both sides?